# For Loop assistance needed

Tags: java, for-loop

I am required to write a for loop that will print the numbers from 1000 down to 4 that are multiples of 6, one number per line.

I have the structure right as far as I know.

```
    public class multiples
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            for(int a = 1000; a < 4; a % 6 == 0);
            {
                System.out.println("a = " + a);
            }
        }
    }
```

I keep getting these errors

```
    multiples.java:5: error: not a statement
            for(int a = 1000; a < 4; a % 6 == 0);
                                           ^
1 error
```

How will I implement the multiples part of this code? Or remedy this error?

Comment: The third part of the for statement needs to be a statement, like a++ or a*=3

Comment: Change a%6==a to a = a-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third portion of the `for` loop is the increment (or in your case decrement), the second portion controls the evaluation of the body (and 1000 is never less than 4), also the semicolon terminates the loop body (and then you have an anonymous block). Try something like

```
for (int a = 1000; a >= 4; a--) {
    if (a % 6 == 0) {
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
    }
}
```

Which you can read as loop from 1000 to 3 decreasing the value by one on each iteration, if the current value is divisible by six display the value.

Of course, you could optimize your program like

```
for (int a = 996; a >= 6; a -= 6) {
    System.out.printf("a = %d%n", a);
}
```

Which will also output every multiple of 6 and was determined by using integer math to divide 1000/6 resulting in 166. And 166*6 = 996. Of course, 6 is the first multiple of 6 greater than 4.

Comment: A minor optimisation: No multiple of six will be an odd number, so there's no need to check them. Use `a-=2` as the last term in your `for` loop.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I think the point of this code is to allow for more checks, for example "is divisible by 3?" I find this much more neat and universally useable.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Added an optimized version, note that once you determine the first and last multiple of 6 it's simple arithmetic.

Comment: @JClassic Perhaps. I actually wouldn't do any of this this way, so I'd say the point is moot.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I like yours better than mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the numbers from 1000 to 4 right. `for` loop takes in `for(init ; condition ; update)`. You can try the following in for loop:

```
for(int a = 1000; a >= 4; a--) {
  if (a % 6 == 0)
    System.out.println("a = " + a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the structure for the `for` loop:

```
for(<variable declaration or init>; <boolean expression>; <statement>)
```

the statement needs to assign a variable to something (an action after the loop has run)

Here is revised code:

```
for(int a = 1000; a >= 4; a--) {  //start with 1000, minus one everytime. (decrement your a variable)
    if (a % 6 == 0) //is "a" a multiple of 6?
    System.out.println("a = " + a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop syntax itself wrong .

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

and try this code

```
for(int a = 1000; a > 4; a--)  // decrement here
{
  if (a % 6 == 0)    // you have to apply condition here only for the correct logic
    System.out.println("a = " + a);
}
```

Comment: little reading required here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html